# Drawing a direction field of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Sketch the direction field of $\,u′=\sin(u)\,$ on the points: $\pi/2,\,\pi,\,3/2\pi,\,2\pi,\ldots$

I'm not quite sure how I should draw the field by only having one set of values.
As example when I wanna draw for the point $\,\pi/2,\,\sin(\pi/2)=1\,,\,$ where exactly do I draw the slope arrow in the sketch? Im aware of doing this when were given a range of values for $x, y$ but how do I use the $x , y$ axis only have given these values? Might sound like a silly question but im really confused by this.

Comment: Please google what a phase portrait is.

Comment: Try to draw them centered at the point. Since there is no x-dependence for your equation you only need to consider the slopes at the u -values.